# I am using Socat to open a serial connection to a cisco switch in an Expect script. I am able to log into the switch but expect commands wont work

Tags: bash, expect, socat

My script is not executing after Socat opens a serial connection to a cisco switch. How to fix this?

```
      #!/usr/bin/expect -f
      socat.exe `tty`,raw,echo=0 /dev/ttyS4,raw,echo=0,setsid,sane
      after 10
      send "\r"
      expect "switch1>"
      send "enable\r"
      expect "*assword:"
      send "PASSWORD\r"
      expect "*#"
      send "sh ip int brief\r"
```

Comment: It has been a while since I used expect. I think you need `spawn socat.exe ....`?

Comment: @SiKing I've tried doing using Spawn but it is still not working as it is suppose to.

Comment: Got it ! I just Modified  - spawn socat.exe - /dev/ttyS4,raw,echo=0,setsid,sane and the script executed perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backticks are a shell thing, not Tcl/expect. The equivalent in expect would be

```
spawn socat.exe [exec tty],raw,echo=0 /dev/ttyS4,raw,echo=0,setsid,sane
```